# Changing image to another image and backforth in Android using imageview

Tags: android

change image when user click on the image and backforth .The problem is it works when image A change to image B ...But i cant get image B to image A

```
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:onClick="fade" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2hi"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:src="@drawable/img2hello"
    android:onClick="fade2" />


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void fade(View view)
{
    ImageView img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

    ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2hi);
    img1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
public  void fade2(View view)
{
    ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2hi);
    img1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ImageView img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the image programmatically? rather than setting it in the xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use view switcher like 
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/viewswitcher.php